# Trying to restric a queryset in Django base on foreign key relationship

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a form in Django that gives the user a limited selection based on a foreign key. To be more exact, the form has 2 fields, a `ModelChoiceField` and a simple text field. This form's purpose is to allow a user to add a `Riddle` to a previously created `Room`. So the goal is to limit the `ModelChoiceField` to only allow the currently logged-in user to add riddles to just their own rooms.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project, Riddle

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'max_players', 'has_actor', 'scenario']

class RiddleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all(),
                                      empty_label=None,
                                      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                      label='Project')

    class Meta:
        model = Riddle
        fields = ['project','description']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.all()
        self.fields['project'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: obj.title
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

User = get_user_model()

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    max_players = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    has_actor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    scenario = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #number_of_riddles = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rooms')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "rooms:project_list",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                #"pk": self.pk
            }
        )

class Riddle(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProjectListView, ProjectDetailView, ProjectCreateView, ProjectUpdateView, ProjectDeleteView, RiddleAddView

app_name = 'rooms'

urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/madeby/<slug:username>', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project_list'),
    path('projects/<slug:username>/<int:pk>/', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
    path('projects/create/', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project_create'),
    path('projects/update/<int:pk>', ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='project_update'),
    path('projects/delete/<int:pk>/', ProjectDeleteView.as_view(), name='project_delete'),
    path('projects/addriddle/', RiddleAddView.as_view(), name='riddle_add'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import View, generic
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DetailView, UpdateView
from .models import Project, Riddle
from .forms import ProjectForm, RiddleForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import Http404
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.contrib import messages

User = get_user_model()

class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'rooms/project_form.html'
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('rooms:project_list username=')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('rooms:project_list', kwargs= {'username': self.request.user})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    #def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     #   context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      #  context['riddle_form'] = RiddleForm()
       # return context

    #def form_valid(self, form):
        #project = form.save()
     #   project_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
      #  project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
       # riddle_form = RiddleForm(self.request.POST)
        #if riddle_form.is_valid():
         #   riddle = riddle_form.save(commit=False)
          #  riddle.project = project
           # riddle.save()
        #return super().form_valid(form)

class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        project_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
        context['project'] = project
        return context


class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'rooms/project_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['riddle_form'] = RiddleForm()
        return context

    #def form_valid(self, form):
        #project = form.save()
     #   project_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
      #  project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
       # riddle_form = RiddleForm(self.request.POST)
        #if riddle_form.is_valid():
         #   riddle = riddle_form.save(commit=False)
          #  riddle.project = project
           # riddle.save()
        #return super().form_valid(form)

    #def form_valid(self, form):
     #   form.save()
      #  return redirect('rooms:project_list')

class ProjectListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = "rooms/room_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.room_user = User.objects.prefetch_related('rooms').get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username')
                )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.room_user.rooms.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["room_user"] = self.room_user
        return context

class ProjectDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Project
    select_related = ('user',)
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('rooms:project_list', kwargs= {'username': self.request.user})

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, "Post Deleted")
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

class RiddleAddView(CreateView):
    model = Riddle
    form_class = RiddleForm
    template_name = 'rooms/riddle_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        project = form.cleaned_data.get('project')
        project_title = project.title
        try:
            project = Project.objects.get(title=project_title)
        except Project.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(self.request, "No project with the title '{}' was found.".format(project_title))
            return super().form_invalid(form)
        form.instance.project = project
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse_lazy('rooms:project_detail', kwargs={'username': self.object.project.user.username, 'pk': self.object.project.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['riddle_form'] = RiddleForm()
        #context['project_id'] = self.kwargs['project_id']
        return context
```

For now, I just have the `Project.objects.all()` but that does not achieve the functionality I want.

I have tried using the `select_related()`, `filter()` methods and the `attribute__foreignattribute` syntax to no success. Any ideas of how I should go about this are welcome! Taking into account how common this operation is, the solution is probably something pretty obvious, but I haven't been able to come up with something to fit my case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the `user` as an argument for the `RiddleForm`:

In `RiddleAddView` you can define `user` as a parameter for the `RiddleForm`:

```py
class RiddleAddView(CreateView):
    ...
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
    ...
```

Then you can use it to restrict the `queryset` in the `RiddleForm`:

```py
class RiddleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(user=user)
        ...
```

Also, you can use the reverse relationship:

```py
class RiddleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'].queryset = user.rooms.all()
        ...
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer! I get this error ```user = kwargs.pop('user')```
From this line ```kwargs['user'] = self.object.project.user``` any idea why?

Comment: oops sorry! Wrong paste the error is: ```'NoneType' object has no attribute 'project'```

Comment: Also some extra info. I have also tried using the user from ```User = get_user_model()``` but I get ```Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>.```.

Comment: I've changed my answer `self.object.project.user` is wrong, it should be `self.request.user` which is the current user.

Comment: Also when you use `User = get_user_model()` you are getting a reference of the `User` model class, you can not use that as a `User` instance, the correct way to get the current user is through `request.user`

Comment: I still get an error :/ . You can see it [here](https://prnt.sc/Bsjke1TvM6ty).

Comment: I think the issue is caused by the line `user = kwargs.pop('user')`. With this line, `RiddleForm` now requires the `user` parameter, so any view that uses the `RiddleForm` will also require a `user` parameter defined in `get_form_kwargs()`. Alternatively, you can handle cases where the `user` is not defined by adding some logic to your code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand where I should pass ```user``` as a parameter. I thought it is passe through the ```kwargs```. Do I need to pass it somewhere else too?

Comment: For example, in a function view, you can instantiate the `RiddleForm` manually like `form = RiddleForm(request.POST, user=request.user)`, but in a class view that has the `form_class` member, like the `CreateView`, the form will be instantiated automatically, so to include additional parameters to the `form_class` you can use `get_form_kwargs()` as I do for the `user` in my answer `kwargs['user'] = self.request.user`.